# The console does not return anything

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user to enter their name and age, and then print out a message addressed to them that tells them the year that they will turn 100 years old.

Here the code I wrote:

```py
def solucion(e,n,AA,c):
    # Constantes
    c = 100
    AA = 2020
    # Soluciones
    X = c - e 
    solucion = AA + X
    return solucion

    # Prints de bienvenida y solicitud de entrada
    print ("Bienvenido! Digite su nombre y separado por un espacio su edad.")
    # Imputs
    n, e = map(float, input().split)
    print (("Hola") + n ("cumpliras 100 años el siguiente año:") + solucion)
```

Comment: where do you get `e` from `X = c - e`?

Comment: This code has a `return` statement that is not inside a function, which is an error.  And also as @LV98 pointed out, the variable `e` is undefined. Is this your real code?

Comment: Be careful when posting the question! You had a function definition which was not visible because of bad formatting! Make sure to always double-check that what you're trying to write actually gets the intended formatting!

Comment: Assuming the code was intended to be inside a function, the `return` statement makes the function exit immediately, before any input or output.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the calculation in a function (I assume you wanted to write a function because of the `return` statement). The function will then return the desired value, which can be taken by the `print()`. Here's a modified version of your code encapsulating the first part in a function. Haven't checked in detail if your code works as expected, though.

```py
def calc_year(e):
    # Constantes
    c = 100
    AA = 2020
    # Soluciones
    X = c - e 
    return AA + X

# Prints de bienvenida y solicitud de entrada
print ("Bienvenido! Digite su nombre y separado por un espacio su edad.")
# Imputs
n, e = map(float, input().split)
print (("Hola") + n ("cumpliras 100 años el siguiente año:") + calc_year(e))
```

I'd personally recommend you dive a little deeper through some tutorial to better grasp some foundational knowledge.

EDIT: Having seen your original code (part of which was hidden): you also have an indentation issue. When you stop writing the function, you should go back to no indentation. You can get very unexpected behaviour if you mess with indentation!